# plotting numerical integration and getting Nintegrand Error

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

[image: the function]

i don't understand about Nintegration, and NumericQ. but I have tried numericQ and Nintegration but somehow the graphic won't come...

[image]

EV[[Lambda]*,[Xi]*?NumericQ,[Gamma]*,[Micro]*,K_]:=([Lambda]^2*([Micro]-[Lambda]))/([Micro]*[Gamma] [[Lambda]+([Gamma]+[Xi])*((([Gamma]/[Xi]*NIntegrate[(Exp[(-[Lambda]*s)/[Xi]]*(1-s)^([Gamma]/[Xi]-1)), {s,0,1}])^K*(1-[Gamma]/[Xi]*NIntegrate[(Exp[(-[Lambda]*s)/[Xi]]*(1-s)^([Gamma]/[Xi]-1)), {s,0,1}]))/(1-([Gamma]/[Xi]*NIntegrate[(Exp[(-[Lambda]*s)/[Xi]]*(1-s)^([Gamma]/[Xi]-1)), {s,0,1}])^K))]+[Lambda]*[Xi]*([Micro]-[Lambda]))

Comment: it will be a little better if you post the complete code needed to reproduce this problem in plain text format that one can copy. But for numerical integrations, you need to use numerical values. That what the error seems to say.

Comment: how to copy my complete code? :(